# TomEE-Service: Where to set the options?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

I'm running TomEE 1.6.0 as a Windows-Service and need to increase the memory settings. On my developer machine i'm just editing catalina.bat, is this also the right place for the windows service? I saw Tomcat once as a Service with a Tray-Icon where I was able to change several settings...but this tool isn't available in TomEE. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Click Start button and search for "Services". There should be a snap-in having this name. Search for TomEE and double click. At the bottom is a textfield where you can enter parameters.